# Parsing csv java

Tags: java, sql, csv

I have an issue while parsing a csv file in Java and after that using it to insert in database.

I'm using the following code:

```
public class CSVLoader {

    private static final 
        String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO ${table}(${keys}) VALUES(${values})";
    private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
    private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";
    private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

    private Connection connection;
    private char seprator;

    /**
     * Public constructor to build CSVLoader object with
     * Connection details. The connection is closed on success
     * or failure.
     * @param connection
     */
    public CSVLoader(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        //Set default separator
        this.seprator = '|';
    }

    /**
     * Parse CSV file using OpenCSV library and load in 
     * given database table. 
     * @param csvFile Input CSV file
     * @param tableName Database table name to import data
     * @param truncateBeforeLoad Truncate the table before inserting 
     *          new records.
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void loadCSV(String csvFile, String tableName,
            boolean truncateBeforeLoad) throws Exception {

        CSVReader csvReader = null;
        if(null == this.connection) {
            throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
        }
        try {

            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), '|', '\'', 4);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

        String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

        if (null == headerRow) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    "No columns defined in given CSV file." +
                    "Please check the CSV file format.");
        }
                System.out.println(headerRow.length);                
        String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);
        questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks
                .length() - 1);

        String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
        query = query
                .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
        query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

        System.out.println("Query: " + query);
                String[] nextLine;
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            con = this.connection;
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

            if(truncateBeforeLoad) {
                //delete data from table before loading csv
                con.createStatement().execute("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            }

            final int batchSize = 1000;
            int count = 0;
            Date date = null;

                        while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

                if (null != nextLine) {
                    int index = 1;

                                        for ( String string : nextLine) {

                                            date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);
                        if (null != date) {
                            ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date
                                    .getTime()));
                        } else {

                                                      ps.setString(index++, string);



                                                }

                                        }
                    ps.addBatch();

                                }
                if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                    ps.executeBatch();
                }
            }

                        ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records

                        con.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(
                    "Error occured while loading data from file to database."
                            + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (null != ps)
                ps.close();
            if (null != con)
                con.close();

            csvReader.close();
        }
    }

    public char getSeprator() {
        return seprator;
    }

    public void setSeprator(char seprator) {
        this.seprator = seprator;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, Exception {

   Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");  
  Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://172.16.0.221:1433/tripicker; useNTLMv2; domain=TEST", "root", "");
CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader(conn);
loader.loadCSV("C:\\lol.csv", "lol", true);

}

}
```

but when I have tested it gives me the following exception:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Parameter #2 has not been set.

the csv is like this:

```
Generation Date |2013-05-22 17:57:08|||||||
Number of rows |122837|||||||
Idrissi|Youssef
cks|grrrr
```

the columns of my table are Idrissi and youssef.

Thanks for your help

Comment: SO is not a place for code review

Answer (score 2):

By reading your code and the CSV file you gave, it seems that the header line you are considering is :

```
Generation Date |2013-05-22 17:57:08|||||||
```

So, when you call `headerRow.length`, it will be 9 (or maybe 8 if the last column isn't considered as it's empty).

So, when you are setting the parameters, you will only set 2 of the 9 (or 8) required parameters, giving you the `BatchUpdateException`.

There are two ways to fix that :

- remove the first two lines of the CSV file
- if you can't manually edit the CSV file, add some code to ignore the first two lines :

  ```
  // Skip the first two lines
  if (null==csvReader.readNext() || null==csvReader.readNext()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException(
          "Unable to skip CSV file headers." +
          "Please check the CSV file format.");
  }

  String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();
  ```

Comment: i have changed this  but it returns an error 2
Query: INSERT INTO lol(     java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Parameter #2 has not been set i still have the same error i thin the issue is comming from the Constructor calling of csv reader

Comment: here is the error  2
Query: INSERT INTO lol(idrissi,Youssef) Values(?,?)java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Parameter #2 has not been set

Comment: @Ech-Charif Can you check if there is an empty line at the end of the CSV file, and remove it if there is one ?

Comment: no i used to verify that but there is no empty line in my csv file

Comment: @Ech-Charif Can you print the parameters in the loop to check what is being set, with something like that : `System.out.println(index+" : >" + string + "<");` ?

Comment: System.out.println(index+" "+string);   1   1 cks  2 grrrr ( its what it is printed)

Comment: @Ech-Charif It seems that there is an empty line between `Idrissi|Youssef` and `cks|grrrr`. This can be due to the use of windows end-of-lines in the file (\r\n), incorrectly detected as two end-of-lines. Can you check that ? If you can't, you can try to recreate the file by hand, to be sur that the end-of-line separators are the same within the whole file.

Comment: Yes, it 's work when i used to write a new csv. but how can i fix this problem for a big csv with a large number of records.the csv file i used to parse and store in a database are generated from another database and i couldn't change it

Comment: @Ech-Charif You can ignore blank lines by adding `if (nextLine.length==1 && nextLine[0].isEmpty()) { continue; }` in the `while` loop, but the best way would be to produce a valid CSV file.